# tcp connection to get imei

Tags: java, android

I am using the following code for the tcp connection

```
public String connectToservertocheckuserstatus(String phonurl, String imei)
        throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(phonurl);
    Socket sock=new Socket("localhost", 123);
    sock.connect(url);
    //con.setDoInput(true);

    // Allow Outputs
    //con.setDoOutput(true);
    //con.connect();
    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
             sock.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
    // give server your all parameters and values (replace param1 with you
    // param1 name and value with your one's)
    writer.write("imei=" + imei);
    writer.flush();
    String responseString = "";

    BufferedReader reader = null;
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
    String line;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        responseString = responseString.concat(line);
    }
    sock.close();
    return responseString;

}
```

But I'm getting problems. My conncetion string is:

```
  String imeiurl = appConstants.ip + "/tel_dir/imei.php";
```

But its not working. Can you tell me whats the problem with it?

Comment: Please post the detail of the problem you are facing and the logcat error dump.

Comment: sock.connect(URL) doesn't even compile. What's your real code?

Answer (score 2):

Also, please avoid saving the IMEI. It's not secure, and it's a privacy issue. Do you want
to track individual devices? If so, use user/password authentication.

Also, the IMEI is a feature of the phone, not the user. What happens when the user loses the phone or has it stolen? It's rather like saying that you're going to track a computer user from a web site by storing the serial number from the user's computer.

Comment: what di i  have alternatives of imei ?? i want to track the users not the devices